# MusiXTeX slur does not offset with note

Tags: musixtex

I'm learning from the `netsoos.mtx` example in the MusiXTeX documentation. Here is the M-Tx file I have created, which I saved as `example.mtx`:

```
Style: SATB
Sharps: 1
Meter: m4/4/0/0
Pages: 1
Systems: 1
Space: 4
%%\font\elevensf=cmss10 scaled \magstephalf\elevensf

{vers1}
1. Alpha, beta, gamma, delta.

a2       g  | a2        g  |]
L: {vers1}
( g4 f ) d2 | ( g4r f ) d2 |]
```

I use `musixtex example` to create the PDF pictured below. In the first beat of the first measure, I have not separated the G and the A correctly. In the first beat of the second measure, I have fixed this problem by moving the G to the right, but the beginning of the slur has not moved. How can I offset the beginning of the slur to stay below the G?[image: snapshot of the PDF generated from the code]

Here is the file `example.tex` that is generated:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% example.tex
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\mtxversion{0.63a}
\def\mtxdate{<8 April 2018>}
\input mtx
\font\elevensf=cmss10 scaled \magstephalf\elevensf
\mtxSetLyrics{vers1}{%
1. Alpha, beta, gamma, delta.}
\input musixtex
\input pmx
\setmaxslurs{24}\setmaxinstruments{24}%
\normalmusicsize%
\nopagenumbers
\tracingstats=2\relax
\hsize=539pt
\vsize740pt
\def\nbinstruments{2}
\setstaffs11
\setclef16
\setname1{ }
\setstaffs21
\setclef20
\setname2{ }
\generalsignature{ 1}%
\parindent 0pt
\elemskip1pt\afterruleskip1.000pt\beforeruleskip0pt\relax
\stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg5\Interligne\interstaff{10}\relax
\readmod{example}
\mtxInterInstrument{1}{4}%
\mtxGroup{1}{2}{1}%
\startmuflex\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip%
\mtxAssignLyrics{2}{vers1}\mtxLyrModeAlter{2}%
\znotes&\zcharnote{16}{\titles{2.0}{}{0}{}{0}{}{0}}\en%
% Bar count 1
\pnotes{2.83}&\islurd0g\ql g\ts0f{-.8}\ql f\nextvoice\mtxVerse\hu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{4.00}&\hl d\nextvoice\hu g\en%
\def\value{0}\def\atnextbar{\znotes\CenterBar{\pausc}{-2}{\value}&\en}%
% Bar count 2
\xbar
\pnotes{2.83}&\islurd0g\roff{\ql g}\ts0f{-.8}\ql f\nextvoice\hu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{4.00}&\hl d\nextvoice\hu g\en%
\def\value{0}\def\atnextbar{\znotes\CenterBar{\pausc}{-2}{\value}&\en}%
\Endpiece%
\vfill\eject\endmuflex
\bye
```

If I need to edit the file `example.tex`, what command would I use to compile it instead of `musixtex example`? Of course, I would prefer to resolve the issue in the file `example.mtx` if possible.

Comment: Just a hint: Sometimes it's worthwhile to click on your own tag https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musixtex to check for potential solutions.

Comment: Does it appear that I have not done so? I am aware of another question where "slur starts before note", but that issue was due to extra spaces in the author's .tex file, while my .tex file is generated by musixtex from an .mtx file and I don't see any extra spaces in it. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

In your example you first start the slur and then place the note a head width to the right. You can solve the problem by inserting the

```
\islurd0g
```

in the brackets:

```
\roff{\islurd0g\ql g}
```

which gives me the attached result.
[image: slur starting at note]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It looks like you have a solution to the problem but you are not using M-Tx. When I make your suggested change to the file example.tex and then run "musictex example" again, it rewrites example.tex from the example.mtx file, overwriting the change and giving me the same output I got the first time.

Comment: Correction: when I run "musixtex example" again

Comment: You are right, I am not using M-Tx, but just Plain. When I have to correct a file regarding a difference in horizontal spacing, I always have to delete first the respective .mx2-file, created by the musixflx-run. Maybe you also need to delete an auxiliary file first, and then restart your run(s).